# What's happening with these edit review histories?

Tags: bug, review

This is the second time I've seen something like this:

[image: bug1]

[image: bug2]

What's causing these odd line breaks? Why is it only showing up every now and then? Can you fix it?

EDIT: This happened again:

[image: again]

Link for above: https://ai.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/546

I'm using Google Chrome on Ubuntu.

EDIT: [Now posted on Meta.SE.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284096/whats-happening-with-these-edit-review-histories)

Comment: What browser and OS do you use? I'm not able to reproduce this on Edge or Chrome on Windows 10.

Comment: Can you tell which URL it was?

Comment: @kenorb [Here's one](http://ai.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/497) where Doxosophoi approved Mithrandir's edit.

Comment: @kenorb I'm not sure which one of yours it was. :P